# Copying a file and adding a permission in the same batch request in Google Drive Api v3

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have the following code that I want to chance using `batch`. In this code, first I create a copy of a file, and then using the `id` of the new file, I am adding a permission.

```
  File readOnlyFile = new File();
  readOnlyFile.Name = newFileName.Replace(' ', '-') + "_assess";
  readOnlyFile.Parents = new List<string> { targetFolderId };
  FilesResource.CopyRequest fileCreateRequest = _driveService.Files.Copy(readOnlyFile, fileId);
  string readOnlyFileId = fileCreateRequest.Execute().Id;

  if (readOnlyFileId != null)
  {
      newPermission.ExpirationTime = expirationDate;
      newPermission.Type = "anyone";
      newPermission.Role = "reader";
      PermissionsResource.CreateRequest req = _driveService.Permissions.Create(newPermission, readOnlyFileId);
      req.SendNotificationEmail = false;
      req.Execute();
  }
```

However, I am puzzled when trying to use `batch` for this task since I will need the id of the newly copied file to add permission. Below is my initial attempt where I do not know how to proceed after `batch.Queue(fileCreateRequest, callback)`. I can add new action to the batch to add permission. But, I do not know how to get the `id` of the file. Any suggestions? I need to do this for three different files.

```
 var batch = new BatchRequest(_driveService);
 BatchRequest.OnResponse<Permission> callback = delegate (
     Permission permission,
     RequestError error,
     int index,
     System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage message)
 {
     if (error != null)
     {
         // Handle error
         Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Permission ID: " + permission.Id);
     }
 };


 Permission newPermission = new Permission();

 File readOnlyFile = new File();
 readOnlyFile.Name = newFileName.Replace(' ', '-') + "_assess";
 readOnlyFile.Parents = new List<string> { targetFolderId };
 FilesResource.CopyRequest fileCreateRequest = _driveService.Files.Copy(readOnlyFile, fileId);
 batch.Queue(fileCreateRequest, callback);
```

Comment: you will need to do this in two calls.  you cant get the response from one call and use it in the second.  Batching isnt meant for something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload and to configure permissions of a file are two different operations that cannot be [batched](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/batch) together. Your approach is correct, you only have to use set up the permissions in a second call.

After uploading the files and retrieving the ids as you do, you have to create a second call to [create the permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create).

There is no way to do it in a single request, because for setting up the permissions you need the id of the file; and that is only created after finishing the upload. If you need any more clarification, please ask me without hesitating.